# return redirect()->route() shows the error

Tags: php, laravel-5

When update function get completed it should redirect to another page `sample.blade`. But it shows the error not defined Here is my code,
In `PassengerController`,

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
 {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
    ]);
    Move::find($id)->update($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('Move.sample')
                  ->with('success','updated successfully');
    //return redirect('Move.sample');
}
```

My routes.php,

```
Route::resource('Move', 'PassengerController');
```

Should I defined this route in routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a route named `Move.sample`

```
return redirect()->route('move.index')
                  ->with('success','updated successfully');
```

`Route::resource` generates the following named routes:

```
move.index
move.create
move.store
move.edit
move.update
move.destroy
```

Comment: Thanks But it also shows the error "Route [Move] not defined."

Comment: Thanks for your explanation

Comment: But the message ,"updated successfully" not showing thought its get updated in my db

Comment: do you have the session outputted in the blade template?

Comment: No,i didn't used any session in my blade

Comment: then that is why your message isn't append to the page

Answer (score 1):

If you have `sample` blade inside `Move` folder, Use return `view('Move.sample')`

```
return view('Move.sample')
              ->with('success','updated successfully');
```

You can only use `route` if you defined route for `sample` view

```
redirect()->route('/sample');
```

And set route for this like

```
Route::get('/sample', 'PassengerController@getSample');
```

And return view `Move.sample` in `getSample` function inside `PassengerController`

```
return view('Move.sample')->with('success','updated successfully');
```

Check official doc says about [resources](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#resource-controllers)

Comment: But why it shows the error when using return redirect()->route('Move.sample')

Comment: @saranya because the route doesn't exist with that name, see my answer